# How to use redux-observable and promise correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-observable

I am using [hello.js](https://adodson.com/hello.js/) to sign in.

`hello('abc').login()` returns a promise.

It did sign in successfully, because hello.js itself saved the token in the local storage.

However, the code below sometimes does not dispatch the action `SIGN_IN_SUCCEED`.

```
export const signInEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(SIGN_IN)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable
        .fromPromise(hello('msft').login({ scope }))
        .map(response => ({
            type: SIGN_IN_SUCCEED,
            payload: response.authResponse.access_token
          })
        )
        .catch(error => Observable.of({ type: SIGN_IN_FAILED, payload: error }))
    );
```

UPDATE: 
Jay's **Pause on Caught Exceptions** way helped me find the error. The code above has no issue. What causes the problem is that first I try to save the token to the store after getting `SIGN_IN_SUCCEED`. Then I use the token immediately once the app sign in to fetch something. So when the **fetch using token** step runs before **saving token in the store** step, it causes the issue which also won't dispatch `SIGN_IN_SUCCEED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I make some assumptions about the things missing in your example (e.g. `scope`, what hello.js does, etc) it works as expected. Here's an example: https://jsbin.com/rasumo/edit?js,output

There must be something else wrong with your code that isn't included here, unfortunately. How did you confirm it's not dispatching the `SIGN_IN_SUCCEED` action? Were there any errors in the console? Have you tried enabling "Pause on Caught Exceptions" in your debugger to see if you're maybe silently swallowing an error somewhere that is preventing the action from reaching your reducers?

Another thing to confirm is that the Promise returned by `hello('msft').login({ scope })` actually does resolve. You could chain a `.then()` to confirm this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice to see you here, Jay! I am using redux-logger and Redux DevTools, both didn't log the action `SIGN_IN_SUCCEED`. Thanks for the help! I will spend more time figuring out what causes this.

Comment: Thanks, Jay!! Your `Pause on Caught Exceptions` way helped me find the error. The reason is because first I saved the token to the store. Then I use the token immediately once the app sign in to fetch something at `componentDidMount`. So when the fetch part runs in front of the save token in the store, it cause the issue.

Comment: @HongboMiao so glad it helped and you found the cause! Cheers!!